# Dagger Component is not sugested in my android studio and causing me building errors?

Tags: android, api, module, dagger

Hoping you are doing well, I am trying to create a simple CRUD using Retrofit, Dagger etc ..

I created my ApiComponent :

```
    @Component(modules = {ApiModule.class})
    public interface ContractApiComponent {

        public void inject(ContractsListViewModel contractListViewModel);
        public void inject(ContractService contractService);

    }
```

I rebuilded my project many times.

I tried after to call the Dagger Component in my Service but it is not been suggested:

```
    public class ContractService {

        public static ContractService instance;

        @Inject
        public ContractApi api;

        public ContractService(){
            DaggerContractApiComponent.create().inject(this);
        }
    }
```

This is my ApiModule :

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    public static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/newconceptsphp";

    @Provides
    public ContractApi provideContractApi(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ContractApi.class);
    }

}
```

I was typing Dagger, my `DaggerContractApiCompnent` has been suggested, it means it is known by the system, then I tried to run my project finally and suddenly it turned red, my dagger no longer known in my editor.

I am trying to rebuild and rebuild and nothing seems to solve the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated if you faced this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is normal, you are missing a method in your ApiModule, returning the service with a Provides annotations.

@Module
   public class ApiModule {

```
  public static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/newconceptsphp";

  @Provides
  public ContractApi provideContractApi(){
    return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ContractApi.class);
  }

  @Provides
  public ContractService provideContractService(){
    return ContractService.getInstance();
  }

 }
```

Add it and I think it is gonna work.

Comment: Okay I will add it